# Change to "january, february...." when user text into textbox "1,2,3..."

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i'm doing a website with mvc 3 + c#
may i know what is the way allowed me to implement the technique as titled ?
when user input 1, 2 ~ 12 then without refresh browser or anything, when the pointer tab away, the value in text box will automatically fading to january, february..accordingly...

Thx for reply =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why not use a select box that has `1..12` as options, but the values for each option is the corresponding month in `january...december`?

Anyway, this should get you going:

```
jQuery('input.monthSelectInput').blur(function() {
    var months = [ 'January', 'February', ... 'December' ];

    if(months[ parseInt(this.value,10) - 1 ]) {
        this.value = months[ parseInt(this.value,10) - 1 ];
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming here that you're using jQuery, since it's in the tags for the question.

Comment: because i'm still new in mvc 3 and i'm weak in those display, effect techniq.. i got a table store in 1~12 while i need to do calculation >.<

Comment: Perfectly done =D add "onkeypress="functionname()" to the textbox and quote this into javascript, lastly change 'input.monthSelectInput' into '#monthSelectInput' while that id was automatically generate by MVC =D Thx ^^

Answer (score 1):

Given this html:

```
<input type="text" id="month">
```

here is the js:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
            "December"];

$("#month").blur(function() {
  $(this).val(months[parseInt($(this).val())-1]).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var year = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Noverber', 'December'];
$('#year').blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(year[value-1]);
});
```